# What is the best practices for the storage for dev and production on Azure blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

what is the best practices for the storage for dev and production, I have one subscription so do I need to create separate storage accounts for both in one subscription? Or any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is a no-brainer that you keep your development and production storage accounts separate. Apart from the reason that somebody might accidentally wipe out important data during development, you also need to consider performance of a storage account. Each storage account has [`some performance and scalability targets`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/) that might get impacted if you use one storage account for many things (dev/production or main application data/diagnostics data etc.).

As to whether you should get a separate subscription for development and a separate one for production, that's a different question all together. However please do keep in mind that [`each subscription has some hard limits on the number of resources it can have`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/). For storage, that limit today is 100. You can't have more than 100 storage accounts in an Azure subscription. If you think you would need more accounts (say a storage account for each developer), then it might make sense to  get a separate subscription for development.

Comment: Thanks gaurav I understand to take separate subscription but it give us extra overhead in terms of cost so if we have one subscription and in that we create two storage account one for dev and another for production. For dev is like a staging version we only have one server for testing purpose only. What you best suggestion in this scenario?

Comment: I hope you remember my answer to your question about costs :). Cost of 2 storage accounts in 1 subscription == Cost of 2 storage accounts in 2 separate subscriptions. Even though managing 2 Azure Subscriptions can be a bit cumbersome, I would still recommend going down that route. It just provides you a nice isolation between your environments and you can control them in a much better way.

Comment: I have to agree with my friend Gaurav here :-), in concerns to cost multiple subscriptions don't matter, it's only when you actually use services aka consume them (so in this case some gigabytes :-))
Honnestly from a POV of segregation and best practices it would be best to fully separate assets by means of different subscription. even if it was just to avoid Oops moments (as in I deployed to prod) or in getting better cost insights per environment , just saying :-)